# Rigid body collision not happening

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I'm trying to make a simple collision between 2 chess pawn. One is animated and the other is not.
[image]
I made the basic rigid body settings but the animated pawn is just passing through the other one.
This is the setting for the animated pawn then the setting for the not animated one.

[image]

[image]

I don't understand where is the problem from..

Thanks a lot !

Comment: pls provide blend file, thx

Comment: here it is, its not in the main scene but in the scene.001 : https://we.tl/t-PRSxMmeyTK

Comment: hello, maybe make a file with only the important objects

Comment: there is only the important objects in the scene 2 of this file

Comment: @a33 Yeah, and all the objects in the other scene which makes this file unnecessary large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've messed up the *Rigid Body World* a lot, not sure what steps you did to get there but here's how you get the animation working:

1. Remove the *Rigid Body* physics from all 3 pawn objects, "Petite cailles.017", "Pied cavalier.003" and "Moto1.003" as well.
2. Select them all (or at least the motorcycle and its pedestal) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply* > *Scale*.
3. Go to *Scene Properties* > *Rigid Body World* and click on *Remove Rigid Body World*.

[image: remove RBW]

4. Go to the *Outliner* window, switch the *Display Mode* to *Orphan Data* in the dropdown menu at the top, expand *Collections*, select all that are called "RigidBodyWorld..." by shift-clicking on them, press <kbd>X</kbd> to delete them.

[image: delete orphans]

5. Now add *Rigid Body* physics to the pawn objects again. Remember to set the motorcycle objects back to *Animated*.
6. Go to the *Scene Properties* > *Rigid Body World* again. The *End* value is at default 250 again, set it back to 950. Press *Delete All Bakes* (this is important, although you've delete rigid bodies before, there might be a cache stored somewhere).

[image: delete bake]

You could now press *Bake* or *Bake All Dynamics* or run the animation from frame 1 and the rigid body simulation would work - which in this case would mean the unanimated pawn would fall through the floor. So I suggest adding another step ;)

7. Enable rigid body physics on the chessboard object "Chessboard.002" as well, set it to *Type* > *Passive*.

Comment: Thank you so much you literally saved me !

Comment: I'd forgot the Orphean Data thing for reseting the rigid body world it will help for a lot of project !

Comment: @a33 Glad I could help. Would you mind considering to accept the answer then?

Comment: sorry i've forgot about that as well